# Line-through animation when hovered

Tags: javascript, html, css

I wanted to do something where I have a line-through a text and when I hover over the text the line retracts.

Here is what I have so far:

```css
#about {
  text-decoration: line-through;
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 80px;
  float: right;
  color: black;
}
#about:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="about"><a href="about.html" target="_new">ABOUT</a>
</div>
```

How can I do this? CSS or Javascript?

Comment: This should be possible with CSS, although you will need to show us what you have attempted so far.

Comment: hello, please give some ruff example what you want actually..? so we can help you..!

Comment: http://www.thmsbfft.fr/#/works       Something like this. When you hover over the "Profile" link the line slowly retracts.

Comment: @sam, please can you include your attempts (HTML, CSS and JavaScript) in the question itself.

Comment: HTML: <div id = "about">
<a href = "about.html" target = "_new"> ABOUT </a>
</div>                                                                                                                CSS: #about {
 text-decoration: line-through;
 text-align:right;
 padding-right: 80px;
 float:right;
 color:black;
}                                                                                                        #about:hover {
 text-decoration:none;
}

Comment: @sam Thanks for adding the code, although it should be in the question rather than a comment (this can be done via the *edit* button). I've added the code into the question for you in this case.

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pseudo-element would be the ideal choice here.

```css
a {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 25px;
  color:black;
  position: relative;
}

a::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top:50%;
  transform:translateY(-50%);
  width: 100%;
  right: 0;
  height: 25%;
  background: currentColor;
  transition:width 0.25s ease;
}

a:hover::after {
  width: 0;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Profile</a>

<a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor.</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is possible although not with `text-decoration: line-through;`. We can reproduce the `line-through` effect by using a pseudo element and animating it accordingly.

In principle:

- Add `position: relative;` to `#about`, this enables the pseudo element to be positioned relatively to it
- Create a pseudo element `#about:after`, giving it `height: 1px;` and `width: 100%;` to replicate the line-through effect
- Position the pseudo element absolutely and use `top: 0;`, `bottom: 0;` and  `margin: auto 0;` to vertically align it
- Add `transition: width 1s;` to animate the width
- Add the hover event with `#about:hover:after` and set the `width: 0;`

```css
#about {
  color: black;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#about:after {
  background-color: black;
  bottom: 0;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 1px;
  margin: auto 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  transition: width 1s;
  width: 100%;
}
#about:hover:after {
  width: 0;
}
```

```html
<a id="about" href="about.html">ABOUT</a>
```

Comment: Thanks! This was very helpful. Is there a way to control which direction the line retracts?

Comment: Yes, if you add `right: 0;` (similar to the answer supplied by @Paulie_D) the line will retract the other way. https://jsfiddle.net/h15umr7a/

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate how you explain your code which will help me learn.

Answer (score 0):

Moving a `text-decoration:line-through` cannot be done via CSS nor JS.

You can, however, use *another element* that you animate, e.g. like so:

```
.strike {
    position: relative;
}

.strike:before {
    content:" ";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 50%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid red;
    width: 100%;
    transition: left 2s;
}

.strike:hover:before {
     left: -120%
}
```

See jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/dcgbhr1b/).